# RDBMS to ADLS - CSV Image processing/Converting in Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, machine-learning, pyspark, deep-learning

I need to bring data(Includes images) from RDBMS to Azure Data Lake by converting to CSV file. What shall I do to bring all the images without effecting on the image quality.

I found some suggestions to use 3rd party library files.

But I need some more information regarding this. Any suggestions will be great help.